# В чём проблема с BIOS?

Tags: ubuntu, железо, bios, uefi

Имею в наличии старенькую BIostar A770E3. Которая выполняет роль сервера. Раньше был при входе в BIOS был CMOS Setup Utility, а сегодня доставал ssd, накатил на него Ubuntu 18.04, вставляю обратно -- CMOS Setup Utility 2011 или 2012 года как не было, вместо него какое-то неюзабельное дефолтное барахло Bios Setup Utiliy 2006 года, которое не позволяет даже запуститься с SSD и какой бы режим загрузки (ahci/ide/raid/ide->ahci и все остальные) я не выбирал -- всегда кидает на Bio Flasher Utility.

В чём может быть проблема? В какую сторону смотреть? Куда рыть?

Comment: 1. boot flag. 2. имеет смысл использовать mbr (а не наверняка умолчальный gpt).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, boot flag - это где? Я использую MBR.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_flag

Comment: @alexanderbarakin у меня этот раздел активный, на сколько я помню. Сейчас проверю, если нет - попробую указать и ещё раз запуститься. Спасибо.

Comment: Почему-то нельзя сделать раздел активным, в чём может быть причина? [скриншот](https://pp.userapi.com/c621702/v621702943/9412b/khjDW9RcQJQ.jpg)

Comment: совершенно не понимаю, что у вас там на скриншоте и предлагаю воспользоваться чем-нибудь попроще, без всех этих красивых изысков. старой доброй программой *fdisk*, например.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin нельзя сделать раздел активным.Ни один из двух на SSD.

Comment: отмонтировать разделы этого блочного устройства не забыли? приложите к тексту вопроса описание того, что вы делаете и что получаете в ответ.